# USB-C computer to DVI-d monitor connection options

Tags: hub, usb-c, dvi

I have Surface Go 2, that contains only one usb-c port. Currently I am using `usb-c to usb 2.0` adapter connected with usb 2.0 hub with keyboard and mouse which are usb 2.0.

Now I want to connect a monitor with dvi-d port. Is there `usb 2.0 to dvi-d` solutions, so I can plug it the hub?

Or do I need to buy usb-c hub, connect to one slot `usb-c to dvi-d`, and to another — current usb 2.0 configuration?

**Update**

I also have `hdmi to dvi-d` cable.

Comment: Please make sure all your *directions* are correct, it makes it so much easier to follow what you're trying to do. A DVI monitor and a USB-C computer need a **USB-C to DVI** connection method. Your descriptions seem backwards, or random.

Comment: Yes, you need a USB-C hub that has an HDMI port or DVI port on it. USB 2.0 to DVI is a bad idea because A) Everything that exists for that conversion doesn't work well, and B) USB 2.0 is too slow for DVI anyway.

Comment: @Romen, thanks, I already bought USB-C hub with HDMI port, it works but, unfortunately with 30Hz frequency even with FullHD resolution, so now I have to buy another one with 60Hz support for FullHD at least